# Python while loop getting stuck during quicksort

Tags: python, while-loop, quicksort

I am trying to write a quicksort function in Python using a while loop and for some reason, my loop will cause sublime to shut down if I don't increase i during EACH iteration (which is not something I want to do as index 0 of the array may change during the loop). Any ideas about why this may be happening or what is wrong with my while loop? Thanks for the help! I bet I am just being dumb somewhere.

```
from random import randint

def quicksort(arr):
    print(arr)
    pivot = arr[randint(0, len(arr)-1)]
    i = 0
    while i < len(arr):
        print('value', arr[i])
        print('pivot', pivot)
        if arr[i] < pivot:
            arr.append(arr[i])
            del arr[i]
        else:
            i += 1
        print(arr)
    print(arr)

arr1 = [3,86,5,75,2,58,6,4,9,7,87,2,1,6,9,90,65,5,1,890]
quicksort(arr1)
```

Comment: Why don't you use a `for-loop`. Like this: `for i in range(len(arr))`

Comment: @Agile_Eagle Because there's a branch where the list is mutated and the index is not incremented.

Comment: @Aran-Fey I got it. Sorry!

Comment: A suggestion: You can replace `pivot = arr[randint(0, len(arr)-1)]` with `random.choice(arr)`.

Comment: What happens if you pivot is 1 ? The conditions will never be True and not sorting will take place. In other scenarios you get a never ending loop and that's why probably your code stalls. .

Comment: You may want to check other implementations of kicksort in python (just google). I recommend [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42418398/quick-sort-recursion) which is very similar to yours. The problem is that yours cannot work. Note that you need to split your array in some way to take into account items lower and higher than the pivot

Comment: @joaquin, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the last element of the list is smaller than the pivot, your function will append it to the end and delete again forever. In fact, this is true even when all the *remaining* elements are smaller than the pivot.